# ng-click doesn't work on different page

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i have two file.html : list.html and popover.html.

i want to add class element when i clicked,
so this way it's work to me on same file list.html :

```
<i ng-class="{'icon ion-ios7-pricetags select':liked, 'icon ion-ios7-pricetags':!liked}" ng-click="liked=!liked"></i>
```

but if i add ng-click="liked=!liked" to different file (popover.html), it's doesn't work.

```
<input type="radio" name="tags" value="Food" ng-click="closeInController(); liked=!liked" ng-model="data.expense">
```

this my code app.js for popover :

```
$scope.closeInController = function() {
   $scope.popover.hide();
};
```

anyone can help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because your popover and list do not share the same scope. You'll need to make sure that your `liked` variable is set on a shared controller scope.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i'm so early for angular.
so, in which files should I add some code?